# which fonts are more suitable to write an article?

Tags: ms-word, word-2010

I am the technical writer and i have started to writing my article using Calibri font it was suitable, but i am looking for the most attractive and most user readable fonts, so guys please help me in my search.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the aesthetics of a technical paper.

Answer (score 1):

That's a highly subjective thing. And what font you're to use will depend largely on who is going to publish your work. Whatever you use, the publisher's going to change things around to fit their own format of course, so as to keep consistency between their products.

Comment: Yup but in my case, i have to publish my article by my own i.e. they will not make any kind of modification on my article, that's why i have to look around the font size, font style etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create attractive and the most user readable fonts, you can go for **Times New Roman, Calibri, and Arial.** However, to make more attractive and readable in documents, you need to format them and emphasize wherever required with bold and italic styles. Differentiate headers and paragraph contents with suitable styles.